# How to use C#8 IAsyncEnumerable<T> to async-enumerate tasks run in parallel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, iasyncenumerable

If possible I want to create an async-enumerator for tasks launched in parallel. So first to complete is first element of the enumeration, second to finish is second element of the enumeration, etc.

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ParallelEnumerateAsync(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> coldAsyncTasks)
{
    // ... 
}
```

I bet there is a way using `ContinueWith` and a `Queue<T>`, but I don't completely trust myself to implement it.

Comment: This would be a better question if you provided a little detail about your use case.  It's unclear to me why one might want to do this.

Comment: If you want *parallel* `async` *ordered tasks* use *TPL dataflow* `ActionBlock`, or *reactive extension* i believe might also work

Comment: Related: [How to implement an efficient WhenEach that streams an IAsyncEnumerable of task results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194212/how-to-implement-an-efficient-wheneach-that-streams-an-iasyncenumerable-of-task)

Answer (score 17):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ParallelEnumerateAsync<T>(
    this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var remaining = new List<Task<T>>(tasks);

    while (remaining.Count != 0)
    {
        var task = await Task.WhenAny(remaining);
        remaining.Remove(task);
        yield return (await task);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more inline with what the OP is asking, plus one

Comment: Could be optimized with `ISet<Task<T>>`, I suppose

Comment: Probably. Measure it.

Comment: In case there is a large number of tasks (more than 1,000), this solution will no longer be efficient. In that case an alternative and more efficient way of sorting the tasks by completion is to use the [`OrderByCompletion`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.TaskExtensions/OrderByCompletion''1(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(System.Threading.Tasks.Task(''0)))) extension method from Stephen Cleary's [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) library.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question right, your focus is to launch all tasks, let them all run in parallel, but make sure the return values are processed in the same order as the tasks were launched.

Checking out the specs, with [C# 8.0 Asynchronous Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#asynchronous-streams) task queuing for ***parallel*** execution but ***sequential*** return can look like this.

```
/// Demonstrates Parallel Execution - Sequential Results with test tasks
async Task RunAsyncStreams()
{
    await foreach (var n in RunAndPreserveOrderAsync(GenerateTasks(6)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"#{n} is returned");
    }
}

/// Returns an enumerator that will produce a number of test tasks running
/// for a random time.
IEnumerable<Task<int>> GenerateTasks(int count)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(async n =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(100, 1000));
        Console.WriteLine($"#{n} is complete");
        return n;
    });
}

/// Launches all tasks in order of enumeration, then waits for the results
/// in the same order: Parallel Execution - Sequential Results.
async IAsyncEnumerable<T> RunAndPreserveOrderAsync<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var queue = new Queue<Task<T>>(tasks);
    while (queue.Count > 0) yield return await queue.Dequeue();
}
```

Possible output:

```
#5 is complete
#1 is complete
#1 is returned
#3 is complete
#6 is complete
#2 is complete
#2 is returned
#3 is returned
#4 is complete
#4 is returned
#5 is returned
#6 is returned
```

On a practical note, there doesn't seem to be any new language-level support for this pattern, and besides since the asynchronous streams deal with `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, it means that a base `Task` would not work here and all the worker `async` methods should have the same `Task<T>` return type, which somewhat limits asynchronous streams-based design.

Because of this and depending on your situation (Do you want to be able to cancel long-running tasks? Is per-task exception handling required? Should there be a limit to the number of concurrent tasks?) it might make sense to check out @TheGeneral 's suggestions up there.

**Update:**

Note that `RunAndPreserveOrderAsync<T>` does not necessarily have to use a `Queue` of tasks - this was only chosen to better show coding intentions.

```
var queue = new Queue<Task<T>>(tasks);
while (queue.Count > 0) yield return await queue.Dequeue();
```

Converting an enumerator to `List` would produce the same result; the body of `RunAndPreserveOrderAsync<T>` can be replaced with one line here

```
foreach(var task in tasks.ToList()) yield return await task;
```

In this implementation it is important that all the tasks are generated and launched first, which is done along with `Queue` initialization or a conversion of `tasks` enumerable to `List`. However, it might be hard to resist simplifying the above `foreach` line like this

```
foreach(var task in tasks) yield return await task;
```

which would cause the tasks being executed sequentially and not running in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanna take an async stream (IAsyncEnumerable) and run `Select` in parallel so the first to finish is the first to come out:

```
/// <summary>
/// Runs the selectors in parallel and yields in completion order
/// </summary>
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TOut> SelectParallel<TIn, TOut>(
    this IAsyncEnumerable<TIn> source,
    Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> selector)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Source is null");
    }

    var enumerator = source.GetAsyncEnumerator();

    var sourceFinished = false;
    var tasks = new HashSet<Task<TOut>>();

    Task<bool> sourceMoveTask = null;
    Task<Task<TOut>> pipeCompletionTask = null;

    try
    {
        while (!sourceFinished || tasks.Any())
        {
            if (sourceMoveTask == null && !sourceFinished)
            {
                sourceMoveTask = enumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask();
            }

            if (pipeCompletionTask == null && tasks.Any())
            {
                pipeCompletionTask = Task.WhenAny<TOut>(tasks);
            }

            var coreTasks = new Task[] { pipeCompletionTask, sourceMoveTask }
                .Where(t => t != null)
                .ToList();

            if (!coreTasks.Any())
            {
                break;
            }

            await Task.WhenAny(coreTasks);

            if (sourceMoveTask != null && sourceMoveTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                sourceFinished = !sourceMoveTask.Result;

                if (!sourceFinished)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        tasks.Add(selector(enumerator.Current));
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

                sourceMoveTask = null;
            }
            
            if (pipeCompletionTask != null && pipeCompletionTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                var completedTask = pipeCompletionTask.Result;

                if (completedTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    yield return completedTask.Result;
                }

                tasks.Remove(completedTask);
                pipeCompletionTask = null;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

Can be used like the following:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = GetIds();
        var strs = source.SelectParallel(Map);

        await foreach (var str in strs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

    static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetIds()
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 20))
        {
            await Task.Delay(200);
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> Map(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(1000, 2000));
        return $"{id}_{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";
    }
```

Possible output:

```
[6:31:03 PM] 1_5
[6:31:03 PM] 2_6
[6:31:04 PM] 3_6
[6:31:04 PM] 6_4
[6:31:04 PM] 5_4
[6:31:04 PM] 4_5
[6:31:05 PM] 8_6
[6:31:05 PM] 7_6
[6:31:05 PM] 11_6
[6:31:05 PM] 10_4
[6:31:05 PM] 9_6
[6:31:06 PM] 14_6
[6:31:06 PM] 12_4
[6:31:06 PM] 13_4
[6:31:06 PM] 15_4
[6:31:07 PM] 17_4
[6:31:07 PM] 20_4
[6:31:07 PM] 16_6
[6:31:07 PM] 18_6
[6:31:08 PM] 19_6
```

Answer (score 1):

My take on this task. Borrowed heavily from other answers in this topic, but with (hopefully) some enhancements. So the idea is to start tasks and put them in a queue, same as in the other answers, but like Theodor Zoulias, I'm also trying to limit the max degree of parallelism. However I tried to overcome the limitation he mentioned in his comment by using task continuation to queue the next task as soon as any of the previous tasks completes. This way we are maximizing the number of simultaneously running tasks, within the configured limit, of course.

**I'm not an async expert, this solution might have multithreading deadlocks and other Heisenbugs, I did not test exception handling etc, so you've been warned.**

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteParallelAsync<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> coldTasks, int degreeOfParallelism)
{
    if (degreeOfParallelism < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(degreeOfParallelism));

    if (coldTasks is ICollection<Task<TResult>>) throw new ArgumentException(
        "The enumerable should not be materialized.", nameof(coldTasks));

    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Task<TResult>>();

    using var enumerator = coldTasks.GetEnumerator();
    
    for (var index = 0; index < degreeOfParallelism && EnqueueNextTask(); index++) ;

    while (queue.TryDequeue(out var nextTask)) yield return await nextTask;

    bool EnqueueNextTask()
    {
        lock (enumerator)
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) return false;

            var nextTask = enumerator.Current
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    EnqueueNextTask();
                    return t.Result;
                });
            queue.Enqueue(nextTask);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

We use this method to generate testing tasks (borrowed from DK's answer):

```
IEnumerable<Task<int>> GenerateTasks(int count)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(async n =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"#{n} started");
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(100, 1000));
        Console.WriteLine($"#{n} completed");
        return n;
    });
}
```

And also his(or her) test runner:

```
async void Main()
{
    await foreach (var n in ExecuteParallelAsync(GenerateTasks(9),3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"#{n} returned");
    }
}
```

And we get this result in LinqPad (which is awesome, BTW)

```
#1 started
#2 started
#3 started
#3 is complete
#4 started
#2 is complete
#5 started
#1 is complete
#6 started
#1 is returned
#2 is returned
#3 is returned
#4 is complete
#7 started
#4 is returned
#6 is complete
#8 started
#7 is complete
#9 started
#8 is complete
#5 is complete
#5 is returned
#6 is returned
#7 is returned
#8 is returned
#9 is complete
#9 is returned
```

Note how the next task starts as soon as any of the previous tasks completes, and how the order in which they return is still preserved.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias thanks. But everything inside of the EqueueNextTask happens inside of a lock, so basically only one thread can do anything with the iterator at any given moment? Any completing tasks would still need to wait for the lock before accessing it?

Comment: You are right, I'm blind. I am deleting my comment. 

Comment: Upvoted. Your solution is certainly an improvement of mine. The only downside I can think of is that in case of an exception it will be wrapped in an `AggregateException`, because of accessing the `Task.Result` property.

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, I still have a lot to learn about all this async stuff. Though it is still seems easier than the regular threading.