# Streaming data via IEnumerable & TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, enumerate, tpl-dataflow

I am getting items from an upstream API which is quite slow. I try to speed this up by using TPL Dataflow to create multiple connections and bring these together, like this;

```cs
class Stuff
{
    int Id { get; }
}

async Task<Stuff> GetStuffById(int id) => throw new NotImplementedException();

async Task<IEnumerable<Stuff>> GetLotsOfStuff(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var bagOfStuff = new ConcurrentBag<Stuff>();

    var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
    };

    var processor = new ActionBlock<int>(async id =>
    {
        bagOfStuff.Add(await GetStuffById(id));
    }, options);

    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
        processor.Post(id);
    }

    processor.Complete();
    await processor.Completion;

    return bagOfStuff.ToArray();
}
```

The problem is that I have to wait until I have finished querying the entire collection of `Stuff` before I can return it to the caller. What I would prefer is that, whenever any of the multiple parallel queries returns an item, I return that item in a `yield return` fashion. Therefore I don't need to return an `sync Task<IEnumerable<Stuff>>`, I can just return an `IEnumerable<Stuff>` and the caller advances the iteration as soon as any items return.

I tried doing it like this;

```cs
IEnumerable<Stuff> GetLotsOfStuff(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
    };

    var processor = new ActionBlock<int>(async id =>
    {
        yield return await GetStuffById(id);
    }, options);

    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
        processor.Post(id);
    }

    processor.Complete();
    processor.Completion.Wait();

    yield break;
}
```

But I get an error

> The yield statement cannot be used inside an anonymous method or lambda expression

How can I restructure my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an `IEnumerable`, but to do so you must block your current thread. You need a `TransformBlock` to process the ids, and a feeder-task that will feed asynchronously the `TransformBlock` with ids. Finally the current thread will enter a blocking loop, waiting for produced stuff to yield:

```
static IEnumerable<Stuff> GetLotsOfStuff(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    using var completionCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var processor = new TransformBlock<int, Stuff>(async id =>
    {
        return await GetStuffById(id);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
        BoundedCapacity = 50, // Avoid buffering millions of ids
        CancellationToken = completionCTS.Token
    });

    var feederTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (int id in ids)
                if (!await processor.SendAsync(id)) break;
        }
        finally { processor.Complete(); }
    });

    try
    {
        while (processor.OutputAvailableAsync().Result)
            while (processor.TryReceive(out var stuff))
                yield return stuff;
    }
    finally // This runs when the caller exits the foreach loop
    {
        completionCTS.Cancel(); // Cancel the TransformBlock if it's still running
    }

    Task.WaitAll(feederTask, processor.Completion); // Propagate all exceptions
}
```

No `ConcurrentBag` is needed, since the `TransformBlock` has an internal output buffer. The tricky part is dealing with the case that the caller will abandon the enumeration of the `IEnumerable<Stuff>` by breaking early, or by being obstructed by an exception. In this case you don't want the feeder-task to keep pumping the `IEnumerable<int>` with the ids till the end. Fortunately [there is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216380/how-to-stop-propagating-an-asynchronous-stream-iasyncenumerable/58237995#58237995). Enclosing the yielding loop in a try/finally block allows a notification of this event to be received, so that the feeder-task can be terminated in a timely manner.

An alternative implementation could remove the need for a feeder-task by combining pumping the ids, feeding the block, and yielding stuff in a single loop. In this case you would want a lag between pumping and yielding. To achieve it, the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)'s [`Lag`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.6/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Lag.htm) (or [`Lead`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.6/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Lead.htm)) extension method could be handy.

---

**Update:** Here is a different implementation, that enumerates and yields in the same loop. To achieve the desired lagging, the source enumerable is right-padded with some dummy elements, equal in number with the degree of concurrency.

This implementation accepts generic types, instead of `int` and `Stuff`.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Transform<TSource, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> taskFactory,
    int degreeOfConcurrency)
{
    var processor = new TransformBlock<TSource, TResult>(async item =>
    {
        return await taskFactory(item);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = degreeOfConcurrency
    });

    var paddedSource = source.Select(item => (item, true))
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((default(TSource), false), degreeOfConcurrency));
    int index = -1;
    bool completed = false;
    foreach (var (item, hasValue) in paddedSource)
    {
        index++;
        if (hasValue) { processor.Post(item); }
        else if (!completed) { processor.Complete(); completed = true; }
        if (index >= degreeOfConcurrency)
        {
            if (!processor.OutputAvailableAsync().Result) break; // Blocking call
            if (!processor.TryReceive(out var result))
                throw new InvalidOperationException(); // Should never happen
            yield return result;
        }
    }
    processor.Completion.Wait();
}
```

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<Stuff> lotsOfStuff = Transform(ids, GetStuffById, 5);
```

Both implementations can be modified trivially to return an `IAsyncEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable`, to avoid blocking the calling thread.

Comment: I added an alternative implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a few different ways you can handle this based on your specific use case. But to handle items as they come through in terms of TPL-Dataflow, you'd change your source block to a `TransformBlock<,>` and flow the items to another block to process your items. Note that now you can get rid of collecting `ConcurrentBag` and be sure to set `EnsureOrdered` to `false` if you don't care what order you receive your items in. Also link the blocks and propagate completion to ensure your pipeline finishes once all item are retrieved and subsequently processed.

```
class Stuff
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class GetStuff
{
    async Task<Stuff> GetStuffById(int id) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    async Task GetLotsOfStuff(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        //var bagOfStuff = new ConcurrentBag<Stuff>();

        var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
            EnsureOrdered = false
        };

        var processor = new TransformBlock<int, Stuff>(id => GetStuffById(id), options);

        var handler = new ActionBlock<Stuff>(s => throw new NotImplementedException());

        processor.LinkTo(handler, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        foreach (int id in ids)
        {
            processor.Post(id);
        }

        processor.Complete();
        await handler.Completion;
    }
}
```

Other options could be making your method an observable streaming out of the `TransformBlock` or using `IAsyncEnumerable` to `yield return` and async get method.

Comment: Right! So I could effectively add the delegate for the handler as an argument to `GetLotsOfStuff`. Since the caller knows what it wants to do with each item, it can just pass in the delegate.

Comment: Yeah that could work, if the caller knows what to do with each item