# Parallelize yield return inside C#8 IAsyncEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, iasyncenumerable

I have a method that returns an async enumerator

```
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<IResult> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        await Something();
        foreach (var item in ListOfWorkItems)
        {
            yield return DoWork(item);
        }
    }
```

And the caller:

```
    public async Task LogResultsAsync()
    {
        await foreach (var result in DoWorkAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

Because `DoWork` is an expensive operation, I'd prefer to somehow parallelize it, so it works similar to:

```
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<IResult> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        await Something();
        Parallel.ForEach(ListOfWorkItems, item =>
        {
            yield return DoWork(item);
        });
    }
```

However I can't do yield return from inside `Parallel.Foreach` so just wonder what's the best way to go about this?

The order of returned results doesn't matter.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Sorry I left out some code in `DoWorkAsync`, it was indeed awaiting on something I just didn't put it in the code above because that's not very relevent to the question. Updated now

**Edit2:** `DoWork` is mostly I/O bound in my case, it's reading data from a database.

Comment: You're not awaiting anything, why does `DoWorkAsync` then need to be async?

Comment: Is `DoWorkAsync` actually asynchronous? You aren't using `await`.

Comment: The design of `IAsyncEnumerable` means that there's pressure from both directions: the producer can't produce another element until the consumer has consumed the previous one, and the consumer can't consume a new element until the producer has produced it. It sounds like you don't want that, which is fine. Since `ListOfWorkItems.AsParallel().Select(x => DoWork(x))` returns a `ParallelQuery<T>`, why not return a `ParallelQuery<T>`? (perhaps with `AsUnordered()` if order doesn't matter). If you need an `IAsyncEnumerable`, you can loop over the `ParallelQuery<T>` and yield each element

Comment: @canton7 I actually didn't know `IAsyncEnumerable` works that way.  That's a great idea, thanks

Comment: @MindSwipe updated the question.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay updated the question.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: What does the `DoWork` method actually do? Is it a CPU-bound operation (calculations) or an I/O-bound operation (web requests/filesystem access)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it's I/O-bound, reading data from a database

Comment: In this case (I/O-bound workload) you could consider making asynchronous the `DoWork` method that transforms each individual item, to stay in the spirit of asynchronous programming (which aims at minimizing the number of blocked threads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by canton7, you could use `AsParallel` instead of the `Parallel.ForEach`.

This can be consumed inside a standard `foreach` loop where you can yield the results:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<IResult> DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Something();
    foreach (var result in ListOfWorkItems.AsParallel().Select(DoWork))
    {
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

---

As mentioned by Theodor Zoulias, the enumerable returned isn't actually asynchronous at all.

If you simply need to consume this using `await foreach` this shouldn't be a problem, but to be more explicit, you could return the `IEnumerable` and have the caller parallelise it:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Something();
    return ListOfWorkItems;
}

// Caller...
Parallel.ForEach(await DoWorkAsync(), item => 
{
    var result = DoWork(item);
    //...
});
```

Although this may be less maintainable if it need to be called in multiple places

Comment: There are two problems with this approach. (1) the PLINQ buffers quite aggressively the produced results. This can be fixed with the option `WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)`. (2) the PLINQ uses the current thread as one of the worker threads, so the caller will be blocked between one `yield return` and the next. This defeats the whole purpose of *Async* in the `IAsyncEnumerable`, and it is not fixable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias For point (2), the method will resume on the thread-pool after the `await`, so PLINQ using that thread won't affect the caller. That's unless there is a synchronisation context, in which case just add `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Yes, most probably it will resume on the `ThreadPool`, assuming that the `Something().ConfigureAwait(false)` will not return an already completed task. But this is not what makes an enumeration asynchronous. To be truly asynchronous implies that at least some of the calls to the `IAsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()` will return not-completed tasks. If all these calls block the current thread and return completed tasks, then you have essentially an `IEnumerable` masqueraded as `IAsyncEnumerable`. It would be more honest to return an `IEnumerable`, and enumerate it on the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes maybe. But if calling `Something()` and iterating over `ListOfWorkItems` are interdependent, having them within a single method may produce more maintainable code. Awaiting `Something()` releases the thread (assuming it is actually asynchronous), then the iteration must occur in a blocking fashion irrespective of where it is called from.

Comment: You have a point. Returning `IAsyncEnumerable` has some merits in this case. This is not the intended usage of this technology though. Returning an `IAsyncEnumerable` is a contract, and creates the expectation that the caller will not be blocked. The implementation of this answer is async only for the duration of `await Something()`, and the rest of the enumeration is blocking, so it breaks the contract. My argument is that the PLINQ is probably not the right tool for cracking this problem.

Comment: Regarding using `ConfigureAwait(false)` to resume on the `ThreadPool`, it should be noted that adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside the `DoWorkAsync` method will have no effect to where the consumer of the `IAsyncEnumerable` resumes after every `MoveNextAsync`. The consumer can configure the enumeration independently from the producer, by appending `ConfigureAwait` to the `IAsyncEnumerable` itself. In case the consumer is the UI thread, and the enumeration happens with the default configuration, the UI thread will be blocked.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a basic implementation that uses a [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2) frοm the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<IResult> GetResults(List<IWorkItem> workItems)
{
    // Define the dataflow block
    var block = new TransformBlock<IWorkItem, IResult>(async item =>
    {
        return await TransformAsync(item);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10, // the default is 1
        EnsureOrdered = false // the default is true
    });

    // Feed the block with input data
    foreach (var item in workItems)
    {
        block.Post(item);
    }
    block.Complete();

    // Stream the block's output as IAsyncEnumerable
    while (await block.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        while (block.TryReceive(out var result))
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }

    // Propagate the first exception, if any.
    await block.Completion;
}
```

This implementation is not perfect because in case the consumer of the `IAsyncEnumerable` abandons the enumeration prematurely, the `TransformBlock` will continue working in the background until all work items have been processed. Also it doesn't support cancellation, which all respectable `IAsyncEnumerable` producing methods should support. These missing features could be added relatively easily. If you are interested at adding them, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216380/how-to-stop-propagating-an-asynchronous-stream-iasyncenumerable) question.

Another imperfection is that in case the `await TransformAsync(item)` throws an `OperationCanceledException`, this error is suppressed. This is the [by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29619) behavior of TPL Dataflow.

---

**.NET 6 update:** A new API [`DataflowBlock.ReceiveAllAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.receiveallasync) has been introduced in .NET 6, that can simplify the streaming of the block's output. There is a gotcha though. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389273/for-a-tpl-dataflow-how-do-i-get-my-hands-on-all-the-output-produced-by-a-transf/62410007#62410007) for details.

Comment: To be clear, because all of the data must be fed in before any results are yielded back, and due to the maxDegreeofParallism, for large inputs (10k for example) things won't actually start coming back immediately?

The 10,000th item wouldn't Post until at least 9989 of the previous items completed, at which point those 9989 items would be set to yield return immediately.

(All of this presumes that Post is blocking when MaxDegreeofParallelism is met so correct me if that's not the case.)

Comment: @CalebHolt nope, the `Post` method pushes a message in the `TransformBlock`'s internal buffer, and returns immediately. In case the buffer is full, the message is not accepted and the `Post` returns `false`. In my example the `TransformBlock` is not configured with a `BoundedCapacity`, so its buffer has unlimited size, and all messages will be accepted. A more sophisticated approach would be to configure it with a reasonable `BoundedCapacity`, and feed the `TransformBlock` with the asynchronous `await block.SendAsync(item);` instead of the `Post`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Theodor Zoulias unfortunately has a small issue: you can't choose to aggregate multiple exceptions so only the first exception is propagated.
Here's a modern solution using [System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) (available
since .NET Core 3) and [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachAsync) (available since .NET 6) in order to limit the max degree of parallelism.

```cs
#nullable enable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow.SampleCode;

public class ParallelExecutionException<T> : Exception
{
    internal ParallelExecutionException(T item, Exception innerException) : base(innerException.Message, innerException)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public T Item { get; }

    public new Exception InnerException => base.InnerException!;
}

public static class AsyncEnumerableExtensions
{
    private static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> AsAsyncEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return await Task.FromResult(item);
        }
    }

    public static IAsyncEnumerable<TInput> AsParallelAsync<TInput>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source, int maxDegreeOfParallelism, Func<TInput, CancellationToken, Task> body, bool aggregateException = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return source.AsAsyncEnumerable().AsParallelAsync(maxDegreeOfParallelism, body, aggregateException, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static IAsyncEnumerable<TOutput> AsParallelAsync<TInput, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source, int maxDegreeOfParallelism, Func<TInput, CancellationToken, Task<TOutput>> body, bool aggregateException = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return source.AsAsyncEnumerable().AsParallelAsync(maxDegreeOfParallelism, body, aggregateException, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static IAsyncEnumerable<TInput> AsParallelAsync<TInput>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TInput> source, int maxDegreeOfParallelism, Func<TInput, CancellationToken, Task> body, bool aggregateException = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return source.AsParallelAsync(maxDegreeOfParallelism, async (e, ct) => { await body(e, ct); return e; }, aggregateException, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TOutput> AsParallelAsync<TInput, TOutput>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TInput> source, int maxDegreeOfParallelism, Func<TInput, CancellationToken, Task<TOutput>> body, bool aggregateException = true, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        if (maxDegreeOfParallelism < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDegreeOfParallelism));

        var channelOptions = new BoundedChannelOptions(maxDegreeOfParallelism) { SingleReader = true };
        var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<TOutput>(channelOptions);

        var parallelExecutionTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
            var writer = channel.Writer;
            var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism,
                CancellationToken = cancellationToken,
            };
            try
            {
                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(source, parallelOptions, async (item, ct) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var result = await body(item, ct);
                        await writer.WriteAsync(result, ct);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception) when (exception is not OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        var parallelExecutionException = new ParallelExecutionException<TInput>(item, exception);
                        if (aggregateException)
                        {
                            exceptions.Add(parallelExecutionException);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            writer.Complete(parallelExecutionException);
                        }
                    }
                });
                writer.Complete(exceptions.Count > 0 ? new AggregateException(exceptions) : null);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException exception)
            {
                writer.Complete(exception);
            }
        }, cancellationToken);

        await foreach (var result in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            yield return result;
        }

        await parallelExecutionTask;
    }
}
```

With this solution, you can choose whether to abort at the first encountered exception (aggregateException = false) or continue processing and throw an `AggregateException` (aggregateException = true) once all the source items are processed.

Comment: 0xced my answer is supposed to propagate the first exception that occurred during the transformation, via the `await block.Completion;` line. Do you have an experimental demonstration that it fails to do so? A known problem in my answer is that `OperationCanceledException`s are suppressed ([by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29619 "Dataflow TransformBlock silently fails if TaskCanceledException is thrown")), but all other exception types are surfaced.

Comment: Regarding your solution, I could argue that the `bool aggregateException` has the wrong default. [Firing and forgetting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61320933/11178549) is not advisable in general. Abandoning deliberately async operations is something that I would expect to find as an extension, like the [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync) for tasks, not baked into implementations. The same applies to the `cancellationToken` argument. You are using it to abandon the enumeration, while operations are still running in the background.

Comment: Somehow I missed the last line of your solution (`await block.Completion;`) when copying it! Indeed the exception is propagated. I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have improved the implementation based on your comments. I made `aggregateException` default to `true` and the code now properly handles cancellation (based on your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70827715/stop-parallel-foreachasync/70827899#70827899). Finally, no more firing and forgetting, the `parallelExecutionTask` is now properly awaited at the end.

Comment: Nice. I have already upvoted your answer. :-)