# Thread-safety of bool flag crossing an async boundary

Tags: c#, async-await, thread-safety

Can the following case be assumed de facto thread-safe? The `bool` flag always starts at false and only goes one way to true or stays as is.
I know it's actually not thread-safe, but is it possible to really break somehow?

In this case the async execution is even strictly ordered and never parallel.

```
bool cancelled = false;

await MyAsyncJob.Process(() =>
{
    if (timeout)
    {
        cancelled = true;
    }
});

if (cancelled)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: You might want to mark the boolean as [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile), or alternatively use a `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: You might? Should? Or even must?

Comment: Oh right, the cancellation source is thread-safe and accessible outside the loop!

Comment: I don't see any problem to this. Based on that the lambda is fully executed.

Comment: BTW, _["**I discourage you from ever making a volatile field**. Volatile fields are a sign that you are doing something downright crazy" - Eric Lippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530556/585968)_. Ohad's emphasis.   Originally from archived MSDN blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx

Comment: Stephen Cleary has made some insightful comments about this issue: *It is not documented, but Microsoft people have assured me that the barriers are always present if await causes a thread switch.* [¹](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649998/does-net-resume-an-await-continuation-on-a-new-different-thread-pool-thread-or) *await injects all necessary thread barriers, so there's no issues around out-of-order reads or anything like that.* [²](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491873/do-i-need-to-synchronize-resource-access-between-tasks-with-the-default-tasksche/59503720#59503720)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the following case be assumed de facto thread-safe? The bool flag...

It's not clear which flag you're referring to.

In your code, the `cancelled` flag will work as you expect, *because* it is checked after the method that sets it is `await`ed. The code running after the `await` will see all side-effects caused by the awaited method.

However, `timeout` does not look thread-safe at all. The awaited code checks `timeout` but is (probably) not `await`ing whatever code *sets* `timeout`.

You could go through the trouble of using locks and whatnot, or you can use the `CancellationTokenSource`, `CancellationToken`, and `OperationCanceledException` provided by the .NET framework for exactly this scenario:

```
try
{
  await MyAsyncJob.Process(() =>
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

By following the [standard pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads), other developers will be able to understand your code more quickly. And you won't have to worry about thread safety at all; the provided framework types take care of it.

Comment: Couldn't you also check `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` after the await-block, avoiding throwing? This assumes of course cancellation is requested inside the await-block on timeout.

Comment: @BenjaminE. The standard pattern is to raise an `OperationCanceledException` exception when an operation is cancelled. You can choose to check `IsCancellationRequested`, but if you pass the `CancellationToken` to any *other* methods, then they will respond with an exception if cancelled (following the standard pattern), so you usually end up needing the exception handling anyway.